# GridView: forecolor of column header

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress

This  Grid column property i can set from the designer, but not from the C # code !!!  Why?  Header.BackColor is working fine.  I can also set any other color for the GridView elements except this.

Comment: Could you please share the code which you implemented and at which event of grid??

Comment: I do not use any events.  just set in programm code the appropriate property for each column headers.  the property for the whole headerpanel.forecolor does not work either...

Comment: .backcolor column.header property are working.

Comment: .forecolor for rows and focusedrow too!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this at runtime you need to set the GridColumn.AppearanceHeader.Options.UserForeColor property to true as well as set the actual color. When you do this via the designer, the property is automatically set to true.

```
gridView1.Columns["FieldName"].AppearanceHeader.ForeColor = Color.Red;
gridView1.Columns["FieldName"].AppearanceHeader.Options.UseForeColor = true;
```

Comment: did as you recommended, but it didn’t help.  I noticed that the columns forecolor automatically changes from white to black and vice versa, depending on the background color set in the program.  those.  somewhere there is a property to automatically set the column forecolor, but I just can not find it ...

Answer (score 0):

Ref: [How do I set the color of a grid column header panel?](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/Ticket/Details/Q200212/how-do-i-set-the-color-of-a-grid-column-header-panel)

The header's BackColor property is ignored in the Skin paint style.

Add the following line to your code to address this issue:

```
gridControl1.LookAndFeel.Style = DevExpress.LookAndFeel.LookAndFeelStyle.Flat;  
gridControl1.LookAndFeel.UseDefaultLookAndFeel = false; // <<<<<<<<  
gridView1.Appearance.HeaderPanel.Options.UseForeColor = true;  
gridView1.Appearance.HeaderPanel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

Reference these for detailed information:
[Gridview - How to change a column's header background color](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t601290/gridview-how-to-change-a-column-s-header-background-color)
[Why Appearance settings of DevExpress controls are not taken into account?](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/K18403/why-appearance-settings-of-devexpress-controls-are-not-taken-into-account)
[Devexpress column header color (each column different color), winform c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34398669/devexpress-column-header-color-each-column-different-color-winform-c-sharp)

The DevExpress skinning mechanism overrides the Appearance object settings. You have a couple options if you need a different background color for the column header:

- Disable skinning on the GridControl by setting the GridControl.LookAndFeel.UseDefaultLookAndFeel property to False and the GridControl.LookAndFeel.Style property to "Flat".
- Handle the GridView's [CustomDrawColumnHeader](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.CustomDrawColumnHeader.event) and fill the column header with a different color.

Comment: thank.  the first two lines were enough and now everything works ;)

Comment: after all, not all is well.  stopped being displayed in one of the columns RepositoryItemToggleSwitch!!!